# Find minimum date in row with multiple data types in Excel

Tags: excel, date, min

I am trying to find the minimum date in a row that has both dates and number data types. I tried to use the `MINIFS` function but that still produces the number value as the minimum, rather than the date. I am restricted to doing this as an in-cell function, rather than in VBA. Also, the data structure is a bit wonky, I know, but it can't be changed.

```
=MINIFS(A2:C2,A2:C2,CELL("format",A2:C2)="D4")
```

[image]

When I enter `=MIN(IF(A6:C6>40000,A6:C6))` I get a #Value error. Excel doesn't like the range before the `>` symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that dates in Excel are calculated as number of days starting from January 1st, 1900.
Thus, if you look at your dates as numbers, you will see that it's in fact a number '44042'.
Knowing that, you can use MIN together with IF formula:

```
=MIN(IF(B5:D5>43831,B5:D5))
```

Where your suggested numbers are in cells B5:D5 and '43831' is 2020/01/01.
Of course, if you have numbers with high values, this solution should be adapted.
Here's a screenshot I made:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISqrl.png)

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't that formula only work if the 'date' is entered as a number? In your snapshot, you are applying the formula to Row 2, but it won't work for Row 1.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Because the date is changed to the number by Excel anyway. It's just shown to the user in appropriate format.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I would be receiving an #value error? Excel doesn't like the range included in the 'B5:D5>43831' portion of the formula. See snapshot in question.

Comment: Hi, Jessica. I've tested with text strings and non-existing dates and it still worked for me. You can also try an ARRAY FORMULA. To do so, you need to enter the formula and instead of pressing ENTER, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, so that the formula looks like this:

    {=MIN(IF(A6:C6>40000,A6:C6))}

In my case, the formual returns the same result.